# Android - Block editable calendar event

Tags: android, events, calendar

I guess not, but just for trying. It is possible add an event programmatically and this event can't be edited anymore? The user just can delete the event, but he can't edit it, for example, he can't edit the date of event.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's possible, but it's going to be complex. You should look at the [Calendar Provider API](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html) and you may wish to see how the [Last.fm app](https://github.com/c99koder/lastfm-android) does things.

Answer (score 0):

try to put the content value `CalendarContract.Events.IS_ORGANIZER` to `true` for the event and `CalendarContract.Calendars.OWNER_ACCOUNT` with the email of the user account when you create the calendar.